# Multiple languages with utf8 in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8, collation

How *exactly* is one meant to seamlessly support all languages stored within postgres's `utf8` character set? We seem to be required to specify a single language-specific collation along with the character set, such as `en_US.utf8`. If I'm not mistaken, we don't have the ability to store both English (`en_US`) and Chinese (`zh_CN`) in the same `utf8` column, while maintaining *any* kind of meaningful collation behavior. If I define a column as `en_US.utf8`, how is it supposed to handle values containing Chinese (`zh_CN`) characters / byte sequences? The reality is that a single column value can contain multiple languages (ex: "Hello and 晚安"), and simply cannot be collated according to a single language.

Yes, I can physically store any character sequences; but what is the defined behavior for ordering on a `en_US.utf8` column that contains English, German, Chinese, Japanese and Korean strings?

I understand that mysql's `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation isn't perfect, and that it is not following any set standard for how to collate the entire unicode set. I can already hear the anti-mysql crowd sighing about how mysql's language-agnostic collations are arbitrary, semantically meaningless, or even purely invalid. But the fact is, *it works well enough*, and fulfills the expectation that `utf8` = multi-language unicode support.

Is postgres just being extremely stubborn with the fact that it's *semantically* incorrect to collate across the unicode spectrum? I know the developers are very strict when it comes to "doing things according to spec", but this inability to juggle multiple languages is frustrating to say the least. Am I missing something that solves the multi-language problem, or is the official stance that a single `utf8` column can handle any language, but only one language at a time?

Comment: "*but what is the defined behavior for ordering on a column that contains English, German, Chinese, Japanese and Korean strings*" - simply put: you can't. Unfortunately collation support isn't Postgres' strongest area and the `ORDER BY` operator doesn't allow to specify a collation for sorting which would be the way to go if you only select a single language. While it can handle the _content_ in multiple languages quite easily, it can't handle the sorting, that's right.

Comment: You could always try `collate = "C"` - not sure how well that works with UTF8 though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that there will never be a perfect way to collate strings across languages.

PostgreSQL has decided not to create its own collations but to use those provided by the operating system. The idea behind this is to avoid re-inventing the wheel and to reduce maintenance effort.
So the traditional PostgreSQL answer to your question would be: if you want a string collation that works reasonably well for strings in different languages, complain to your operating system vendor or pick an operating system that provides such a collation.

However, this approach has drawbacks that the PostgreSQL community is aware of:

- Few – if any – people decide on an operating system based on the collation support it provides.
- PostgreSQL's sorting behaviour depends on the underlying operating system, which leads to frequent questions by confused users on the mailing lists.
- With some operating systems collation behaviour can change during an operating system upgrade, leading to corrupt database indexes (see for example [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CB4D1C6BAA80CF146CB0D4F2%40eje.credativ.lan)).

It may well be that PostgreSQL changes its approach; there have been repeated efforts to use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) libraries instead of operating system collations (see for example [this recent thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/85364fde-091f-bbc0-fec2-e3ede39840a6%402ndquadrant.com)), which would mitigate some of these problems.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. How unfortunate. I've been waiting to jump on pg for a real project since replication was added to core in 9.0. I'll have to plan my entire project to see if I can live without ever sorting on user-provided utf8 strings.

You make mention of operating systems with built-in collations that can tackle this scenario. Based on your links, it seems CentOS is one of them? What terms should I be searching for to learn which operating systems support this setup, and how I would go about configuring the OS?

Comment: CentOS is a RedHat clone, right? I could reproduce the results with RedHat Linux, and the component that provides collation support there is glibc. Are there any Linuxen that don't use glibc? I'd expect that for this issue it does not really matter which Linux distribution you use. What I'd do is test strings in various languages with the `sort` command. That uses OS collations, and this way you can test if the sorting order works for you.